# Issues at listenings events on Socket.io with Nestjs

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I have some problems when trying to listen to specific events on socket.io.
I initiate ws server on the nest like their tutorial, also the connection is ok but when I try to connect in frontend the socket object returns properties like: `{..., "connected": false, "disconnected": true}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOD7t.png)

nest code image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx0VU.png)

when I am calling emit on server-side

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaByb.png)

and the response from the server receives an updated JSON, but I can't hear the `progress` event,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6UQp.png)

Comment: Don't use images on StackOverflow. The fact that they redirect to another webpage is a hindrance in helping, code can't be copy-pasted, and it can be harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using Socket.IO v3 which [isn't yet supported by NestJS](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5676) yet. Downgrade to version 2.